# Recursive function in Reactjs Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to update the state using react Hooks `useState();` ?

Here is an example :

I have global state on top of the app:

```
const [familyTree, setFamilyTree] = useState([
    {
      fam_id: 1,
      name: "No name",
      attributes: {
        "Key1": "*",
        "Key2": "*",
      },
      children: [
        {
          fam_id: 2,
          name: "No Name2",
          attributes: {
            "Key1": "*",
            "Key2": "*",
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);
```

I have a current object to update the global state:

```
let res = {
          fam_id: 2,
          name: "No Name2",
          attributes: {
            "Key1": "Update this",
            "Key2": "*",
          },
        },
```

Recursive function in this case helps me to update global state with matched ID, but I have problem now,

```
const matchAndUpdate = (updater, target) => {
      if (updater.fam_id === target.fam_id) {
        target.name = updater.name;
        target.attributes = updater.attributes;
      }

      if ("children" in target && Array.isArray(target.children)) {
        target.children.forEach((child) => {
          matchAndUpdate(updater, child);
        });
      }
    };
    familyTree.forEach((g) => {
      matchAndUpdate(res, g);
      setFamilyTree({ ...g }); // here is my try, this works on start, but on secound update i got error about forEach is not a function...
    });
```

**I don't know where to update state** on correct way?

Thanks, o/

Comment: It looks like you are setting family tree equal to an object, which would not have the `forEach` function.  Are you trying to set it to an array instead?  It looks like you are initializing it to an array.

Comment: Hi, what are you recommend? It's just my try...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you update state inside of `forEach()`.

Maybe you should use .map and update state then at the end of check array.

This is the solution:

```js
const matchAndUpdate = (updater, children) => {
    return children.map(_child => {
      if (updater.fam_id === _child.fam_id) {
        return {
          ...updater,
          children: _child.children && Array.isArray(_child.children) ? matchAndUpdate(updater, _child.children) : null
        };
      } else {
        return {..._child,children: _child.children && Array.isArray(_child.children) ? matchAndUpdate(updater,_child.children) : null};
      }
    });
  };
```

This will return and array of children, so you will begin from the initial array:

```js
 const finalFamily = matchAndUpdate({ fam_id: 1, name: "Name" }, familyTree);
```

`finalFamily` will be the final updated array.

You can update the state like this:

```js
// Option 1:
setFamilyTree(matchAndUpdate({ fam_id: 1, name: "Name" }, familyTree);

// Option 2:
const newFamilyTree = matchAndUpdate({ fam_id: 1, name: "Name" }, familyTree);
setFamilyTree(newFamily);
```

--- NEXT QUESTION-- -

I understand that you want to create a method to push new children to child specified by id.

I developed a method that maintains attributes and old children:

```js
  const addChildrenToChild = (parent,numChildren) => {
    const arrayChildren = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {

      arrayChildren.push({
        fam_id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
        name: "No name",
        attributes: {
        key1:"",
        key2:""
        },

      });
    }

    return {...parent,children:parent.children && Array.isArray(parent.children) ? parent.children.concat(arrayChildren) : arrayChildren }
  }
```

And upgrade `matchAndUpdate` to maintains old children

```js
 const matchAndUpdate = (updater, children) => {
    return children.map(_child => {
      if (updater.fam_id === _child.fam_id) {
        return {
          ...updater,
          children: updater.children
          //Filter updater children 
            .filter(_childFiltered =>
              _child.children && Array.isArray(_child.children) ? 
              //check if exists new child in old children
              _child.children.some(
                _childToCheck => _childToCheck.fam_id !== _childFiltered.fam_id
              ) : true
            ) 
            //concat old children and check to update
            .concat(
              _child.children && Array.isArray(_child.children)
                ? matchAndUpdate(updater, _child.children)
                : []
            )
        };
      } else {

        return {
          ..._child,
          children: 
              _child.children && Array.isArray(_child.children)
                ? matchAndUpdate(updater, _child.children)
                : []
        };
      }
    });
  };
```

And now. You can use the other method at the same time to add new children:

```js
// Now we are going to add new children to the first element in familyTree array, and maintains old children if it has.
const newFamilyTree = matchAndUpdate(
    addChildrenToChild(familyTree[0], 10),
    familyTree
  );

setFamilyTree(newFamilyTree);
```

Comment: I have a system to add new children from for loop and push method : https://pastebin.com/t1BWVkKL

This is an afterthought, how to fill in correctly again state... 

I tried to call a set method and {...oldState, newState (with loop and pushed arrays) }
As a result i getting children but parent gone...

Comment: You should use other type of id, because it's possible that one of them have the same value and fail the previous void explained matchAndUpdate. You can add random letters too